# Loop through the object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like

```
{ a: 2.078467321618,
  b :13521.4,
  c : 4503.9,
  more...}
```

(In debug mode)

I want to loop through the object  and separate key and value; 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Serious question: Did you try Google? You can copy/paste your title and get more than enough references...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way to do it is to make it via foreach:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do something with the key and obj[key], which is val
    }
}
```

Note: here we check if the key belongs to our object, but not to its prototype via `hasOwnProperty` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var val = obj[key];
    ...
});
```

Comment: This implies that `keys` and `forEach` are implemented which will work in most modern browsers. But for IE you will need IE9 or higher. See http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/ for more information on ECMA5 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the following:

for(var key in object){
    var value = object[key];
    //now you have access to "key" and "value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
for(var key in object){
    alert(key);// will give key
    alert(object[key]);// will give value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple:

```js
for (var key in object) {
   // do something with object[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var sum = 0;
var obj = {prop1: 5, prop2: 10, prop3: 15};

for each (var item in obj)
{
 sum += item;
}
```

Result is sum = 5+10+15

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var keys=Array();
var values = Array();

for (var key in obj) {
//has own property is checked to bypass inherited properties like prototype    
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    keys.push(key)';
    values.push(obj[key]);

    }
}
```

//following are the keys and values separated,do whatever you want to do with them

```
console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
var obj = { a: 2.078467321618, b :13521.4, c : 4503.9 };
var keyArr = [];
var valArr = [];

//iterate obj
$.each(obj, function(k, v) {
    //add items to the keyArr from obj's keys.
    keyArr.push(k);
    //add items to the varArr from obj's keys.
    valArr.push(v);
});

//show the result
alert(keyArr);
alert(valArr);
```

see the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bauangsta/KdZrA/